# set textview onload and not on itemclick in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a listview populated from a table with a simple adapter. Now, I can change the value of a textview if I click the list item, like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = controller.getOld();
            // If users exists in SQLite DB
            if (userList.size() != 0) {




                // Set the User Array list in ListView
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(OldTips.this, userList, R.layout.old_tips, new String[] {
 "userId", "tara","ora_meci" ,"echipa_acasa","echipa_deplasare","cota","pronostic","explicatii","rezultat"}, new int[] { R.id.userId, R.id.tara , R.id.ora_meci, R.id.echipa_acasa, R.id.echipa_deplasare, R.id.cota,R.id.pronostic,R.id.explicatii,R.id.rezultat});
                final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                myList.setAdapter(adapter);




                 myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                                long id) {

                          //  Object obj = myList.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                         // String value= obj.toString();

                            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.echipa_acasa);
                           // String nume_campanie = textView.getText().toString(); 
                            textView.setText("value of header text");




                        }
                    });
```

Question: is it possible to change the textview value onload or something like this and not onclick of the item from the listview?

Comment: set the textview outside the OnItemClickListener

Comment: it will not change because I have 2 layouts: the main layout where is the list of the mainactivity and the xml where are defined the textviews which are  included in the list.